# PHPCS rule for type hinting

Tags: php-7.1, phpcs

Is there a rule to check all functions for type hinting?

```
/**
 * Set the part name.
 *
 * @param   string    $name   The part name.
 */
public function setName(string $name) : void
{
    $this->name = $name;
}
```

So for example it has to have a type in front of the argument and the function has to have a specified return type.

Comment: Please accept the answer given below. It is the correct answer to your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### 2019 update - even Smarter

In time, my previous answer - `TypeHintDeclarationSniff` - has shown as very buggy. To be specific:

```
 public function anotherMethod(int $value)
 {
     // $value is known integer
     $this->someMethod($value);
 }


 /**
  * @param string $value
  */
-private function someMethod($value)
+private function someMethod(string $value)  // here should be "int"
 {
 }
```

Missed cases:

```
public function getItems() // here should be "array"
{
    return ['Statie', 'EasyCodingStandard', 'Rector'];
}
```

Or:

```
public function getResult() // here should be "float"
{
    if (true) {
        return 5.2;
    }

    return 5.3;
}
```

Or even breaks the code with parent type in `/vendor`. Why? Because it's based on strings and token, not a static analysis of the code.

This made many people very angry, after I recommended them this sniff. Obviously.

---

## How to do it Better?

I wrote a tool called Rector (https://github.com/rectorphp/rector), that takes into account other variables and other classes and their types.

**That way you can complete type declarations to a code without any `@param` or `@return` annotations**.

---

## How to use It?

Install:

```
composer require vendor/bin/rector
```

Setup `rector.yaml` config:

```
# rector.yaml
services:
    Rector\Php\Rector\FunctionLike\ParamTypeDeclarationRector: ~
    Rector\Php\Rector\FunctionLike\ReturnTypeDeclarationRector: ~
```

Use:

```
vendor/bin/rector process src --dry-run # preview
vendor/bin/rector process src # change
```

That's it!

### Read Behind the Scenes

- [How to Complete Type Declarations without Docblocks with Rector](https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2019/01/03/how-to-complete-type-declarations-without-docblocks-with-rector)
- [The Rocket Science Behind Migration of Docblock Types to PHP Typehints](https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2018/12/10/rocket-science-behind-migration-of-docblock-types-to-php-typehints/)

---

**Initial answer**:

You can use **[TypeHintDeclarationSniff](https://github.com/slevomat/coding-standard#slevomatcodingstandardtypehintstypehintdeclaration-)** from [Slevomat/CodingStandard](https://github.com/slevomat/coding-standard) for this.

I use it for over a year and it works perfectly.

Comment: I looked at it and it fits mostly my requirement. But how do you handle long lines like: `public function getUrlForRoute(string $routeName, array $parameters = []) : string` which are longer than the allowed 80 chars?

Comment: There is `PHP_CodeSniffer\Standards\Generic\Sniffs\Files\LineLengthSniff` for that. I set it to 120 chars. 80 is way to strict for me and screen width of today's screen :)

Comment: @Pascal, in that case, you should use a multiline method signature.  SO won't let me add a multiline code example here as a comment.